# Comparison of cohomologies of spaces over fields.

Tags: field-theory, homology-cohomology

If X and Y are two connected topological spaces and over Complex number field both spaces have same cohomology groups. If we restrict coefficients over field of rational numbers then the cohomology groups of X and Y are same or not? More general what happens with cohomology when we restrict or extent the coefficients over the fields.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "the same" over $\mathbb{C}$. If you mean isomorphic as abstract groups then $X = S^1, Y = S^1 \vee S^1$ is a counterexample. If you mean isomorphic as complex vector spaces then the answer is yes if the homology of $X$ and $Y$ is finitely generated (use universal coefficients twice) but I'm not sure what happens in the general case.

Comment: I mean isomorphic as complex vector spaces.